# No cycles hair rendering options in 2.78?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair

As you can see in the image, there are no cycles hair rendering options (at least where they were in previous versions). Did they remove these options in 2.78 for some reason?

[image]

Comment: FYI: Exists in my 2.78  2016-09-26 build...

Answer (score 9):

They are now located in the geometry panel under render settings:

[image: the new location of the hair settins, under render settings > geometry]

These settings are not actually per particle system as the location in the particle panel would imply, they're actually per scene. So not only are you not able to adjust them per system, what settings you have will be ignored when the model is linked into another file. Where you would then need some other object with hair particles to be able to set them up locally!

By placing them under render settings, the above issues and confusion are solved.

Comment: Hmm... That assumes we want every hair particle system to use the same geometry type. There are cases when this is not true.

Comment: While that might be useful, it is not supported in Cycles and never has been. The location of the panel previously gave a false impression that this was possible.